# Navigation Up button not working in Preference Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, settings, up-button

I am using ActionBarSherlock and in my Preference Activity, as soon as I add the @Override onOptionsItemSelected function, I get an error.

The error - 
`The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type SettingsActivity must override or implement a supertype method`

Is this wrong?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    // Following method throws the error
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // <-- Error
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  // <-- Error
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ABS, make sure you're using `SherlockPreferenceActivity` instead of `PreferenceActivity`. Also, be sure to import `MenuItem` from the right package.

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that. Thanks a lot for your help.